# Dúvida sobre o System.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: java, time

Estava discutindo com um amigo agora pouco sobre a origem do número que resulta desse método. De onde ele vem? Ele é contado desde quando? Ele *reseta*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ele vem do sistema operacional.

O SO é carregado e pega um estado inicial contido na memória da máquina (precisa ter uma bateria ou estar ligado) e/ou de uma fonte externa (internet ou outra forma de entrada) e pega quanto tempo passa a cada ciclo do processador (ele mesmo tem essa informação nele).

O processador vai incrementando um valor em um local a cada ciclo de execução.

O sistema operacional pode ter diversos mecanismos para lidar com isso.

Por exemplo, ele diz que quer essa informação a cada período de tempo e o processador sinaliza a cada tantos ciclos (na verdades chamamos de *ticks* que pode não ser o ciclo em si) para calcular quanto tempo se passou daquele estado inicial. Então ele pode incrementar o tempo passado que ele controla.

Ele pode só verificar quando é solicitado por alguma aplicação (isto costuma ocorrer o tempo todo) e calcular o tempo passado somando o estado inicial que ele obteve (que pode ser atualizado sob certas circunstâncias) com o tempo passado com os `ticks` incrementados e o tempo que leva cada um deles.

Existe hardware que pode fazer isso e o SO só precisa pegar o valor pronto.

Obviamente que se o sistema operacional não tem como saber o hora exata quando ele inicia este número estará errado. Não existe mágica.

Este período pode ser maior que 1 milissegundo, por isso muitas vezes não se pode usar este tipo de informação para verificar tempo passado em uma operação, como muitas pessoas fazem para avaliar performance. Mesmo com tempos menores haverá discrepância. Então só use para saber o horário atual, não para medições de tempo.

O número que o Java pega é um [*timestamp*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp) que é uma quantidade de tempo que passou a partir de um momento no tempo pré-determinado. No caso ele usa o padrão adotado pelo Unix, então é o momento inicial do dia 1 de Janeiro de 1970 ([veja como está agora](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/)).

Se estiver tudo correto na máquina ele não *reseta*.

Se o controle do *timestamp* for feito com um dado pequeno pode ser que um dia ele dê algum problema e pode voltar ao momento inicial de 1970, mas isso é um problema de implementação específico.

[Documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).